# Looking for an anime with an impoverished town and abusive father

Tags: hunter-x-hunter

I’m thinking of an anime but I only remember a flashback about one character (possibly a  villain character). It’s bugging me that I can’t remember what the anime was. I’m sure I’ll remember the main story once somebody says the title but right now this is just an unassociated fragment in my head so here’s what I remember…

It starts out with a young boy and his father living in an impoverished sort of town where they both work at the same factory. The narrator (female I think) says that for this kid there were only two moments in his life that he valued: one was when he fell ill and his father stayed by his side, changing the wet towel on his head. I can’t remember the other moment.

His father is a mean drunk or something who pretty much takes all the money the boy makes and probably beats him too. Anyways, the boy finds out from a person at his work that it was a neighbor lady who stayed by his side while he was ill and not his father (and so his cherished memory was tarnished). His second valued memory was true, but I can't remember it.

So one day some other people gang up on and start beating the crap out of the boy when he spots his father. The boy looks over at him as if asking for help. His father looks at him for a moment but then looks away and carries on his merry way.

That’s all I remember... Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you remember what any of the characters look like?

Answer (score 13):

Oh! I figured it out! It took me awhile searching through a few series I thought it might have been. I thought it could have been a minor Neo-Nazi or Czech S.S. character from Monster, the Comrade “villain” from Gun X Sword, the perfectionist character from the last story arc in The Twelve Kingdoms, or one of the rich & borderline-insane old men from Kaiji or Akagi.

But then it dawned on me... Hunter X Hunter (2011)! I found in the first ten minutes of episode 80.

It was a few details off in the previous description but it’s the story of the youth of Gyro (the leader of NGL’s underground). We’re never told what happens to him but I can only assume the worst if you saw the episode. I think I had my memory lapse because his name, position, and story of youth are all that are mentioned without any sort of introduction of his character into the storyline. Seems sort of suspicious to me…

I’m sorry about answering my own question kuwaly and other people who may have been researching this. Have a good day.

Comment: Answering your own question is perfectly fine! Glad you found your answer! :)

Answer (score 0):

Michiko & Hatchin has abusive stepparents at the beginning, in an impoverished country.

Comment: Can you expand a little on this to help the poster? Maybe explain how Hatchin could be mistaken as a boy and etc.